# ZF2 - Using post redirect get and redirecting to a URL with params

Tags: zend-framework2

To manage forms in `ZF2 I` am using Post `Redirect Get`. The documentation on this can be found [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-postredirectget).

Up until now my redirects have been relatively simple and I have been able to re-direct to routes, however I had a situation where I needed to redirect to a specific URL with specific parameters.

```
www.mysite.com/users/edit/id/1/page/4
```

The route is users/edit and I needed to set parameters `id = 1` and `page = 4` so that after I have edited the users data I am redirected back to the users page.

Typically my controller looks like this::

```
    public function indexAction()
{
    $user_id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    $page_id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('page', 0);

    $prg = $this->prg('users/edit');

    //If user has posted, execute the re-direct
    if ($prg instanceof Response) {
        return $prg;
    } elseif ($prg === false) {
        //First time form has been loaded set the view
    }

   //User has hit submit, do submit stuff here
```

The above example will not work as the `redirect` is not `re-directing` to the url with params. To get it to work you need to updatethe following::

```
Replace:: $prg = $this->prg('/user/edit/id');
```

to::

```
$prg = $this->prg('/user/edit/id/'.$user_id.'/page/'.$page_id.'',true);
```

True switches PRG to a URL from a ROUTE...

Now when a user submits data they will be redirected to the URL as defined.

Of course you could simply setup a post route... but then you would need more than one action...

This was my solution and I could not figure out a better way to do this. So my question is simply, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug with PRG. It can handle the following situations:

1. Redirect to a URL (no route name, the url for that route)
2. Redirect to a route without parameters
3. Redirect to the current matched route

For the first scenario, you have to pass on `true` as the second parameter.

```
// True to keep matched params
$url = $this-url()->fromRoute('foo/bar/baz', array(), true); 

// True to note PRG it's a URL, no route name
$prg = $this->prg($url, true);
```

For the second scenario, it's the most common one:

```
$prg = $this->prg('foo/bar/baz');
```

The last scenario uses the currently selected route. We often do this for routes with parameters where the route parameters must be reused and we PRG to the same route:

```
$prg = $this->prg();
```

If you have a route on which you want to apply PRG and this route contains route match parameters, I'd suggest you to use `null` (or, don't supply any parameters). If this route of PRG differs from the one you are currently using, you have to supply the URL with it.